# i want .htaccess code know if php is installed on the server

Tags: .htaccess

I want .htaccess code to know if php is installed on the server.
If it is not installed i will deny access to any php file.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the IfModule directive: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#ifmodule